# regarding the error message of nvalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, databricks, python-datetime, python-dataclasses

I was trying to run the following two segments, a part from this [databricks tutorial](https://pages.databricks.com/rs/094-YMS-629/images/Fine-Grained-Time-Series-Forecasting.html?_ga=2.186954283.2030079703.1618072560-81079421.1618072560).

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
from math import sqrt
from datetime import date

# get historical actuals & predictions for comparison
actuals_pd = history_pd[ history_pd['ds'] < date(2018, 1, 1) ]['y']  # line 1
predicted_pd = forecast_pd[ forecast_pd['ds'] < date(2018, 1, 1) ]['yhat']  # line 2
```

However, I got the error message of `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date` from     `predicted_pd = forecast_pd[ forecast_pd['ds'] < date(2018, 1, 1) ]['yhat']`..  The one in the previous line, which seems very similar, does not have this error.  I also printed types of `predicted_pd` and `actuals_pd` for the reference.

[image]

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-748394f8994f> in <module>
----> 1 predicted_pd = forecast_pd[ forecast_pd['ds'] < date(2018, 1, 1) ]['yhat']

~\Anaconda3\envs\sparkenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     64 
---> 65         return method(self, other)
     66 
     67     return new_method

~\Anaconda3\envs\sparkenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    368         rvalues = extract_array(other, extract_numpy=True)
    369 
--> 370         res_values = comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
    371 
    372         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)

~\Anaconda3\envs\sparkenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    228     if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues):
    229         # Call the method on lvalues
--> 230         res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
    231 
    232     elif is_scalar(rvalues) and isna(rvalues):

~\Anaconda3\envs\sparkenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     64 
---> 65         return method(self, other)
     66 
     67     return new_method

~\Anaconda3\envs\sparkenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in wrapper(self, other)
    116             other = _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    117         except InvalidComparison:
--> 118             return invalid_comparison(self, other, op)
    119 
    120         dtype = getattr(other, "dtype", None)

~\Anaconda3\envs\sparkenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\invalid.py in invalid_comparison(left, right, op)
     32     else:
     33         typ = type(right).__name__
---> 34         raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
     35     return res_values
     36 

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date
```

Comment: Can you try: `forecast_pd[ forecast_pd['ds'] < pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')`

Comment: @Erfan, thanks for the answer. It works. Would you like to explain why this modification works, and why the actuals_pd = history_pd[ history_pd['ds'] < date(2018, 1, 1) ]['y'] does not need this modification? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas dates default to `datetime64[ns]`. So you don't want to compare them to `datetime.date` objects. Instead, you can just use a date string and pandas will handle the comparison corectly. Also, if you use `loc` to specify the rows and columns, you will get a cleaner syntax than in your examples.

```
datestr = '2018-01-01'
actuals_pd = history_pd.loc[history_pd['ds'] < datestr, 'y']  # line 1
predicted_pd = forecast_pd.loc[forecast_pd['ds'] < datestr, 'yhat']  # line 2
```